# How can I configure allowed number of GET parameter characters in uWSGI?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am running Django with nginx + uWSGI.

Having just moved from local dev to a staging server, I have discovered that a particular GET request we make has a long query string. Trying to debug, it seems that uWSGI is not accepting this query string based on length - I can pass short strings and it works, over a certain length I start getting 502 bad gateway errors.

I couldn't find anything about this on the uWSGI site or via google searching. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 14):

Found the solution, it is easy enough. Just need to increase uWSGI buffer-size, eg:

buffer-size = 32768

Comment: Also helped me resolve a problem with uWSGI and Flask on Heroku. I was getting 503 errors with an empty response when handling requests with lots of parameters, but no traceback.

The log entries "[WARNING] unable to add HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size" finally led me to the solution.