# 502 Bad Gateway ngnix for magento application

Tags: magento, nginx

Many times I browse Magento web site, I am getting 502 bad gateway error at Nginx.!
Before this error page is taking 89 seconds to load.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWzIG.jpg)

Nginx Log error :-

recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 1.0.0.1, server: www.example.com, request:

My Nginx configuration below :-

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
```

Comment: May i know how did you exactly solve your problem? @Nataraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [the config files provided by Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento)?

What you have is an Nginx problem, not a Magento problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22792850/763468

Comment: I am also getting same error, i am using magento 2.3.3 in Centos - Nginx how to solve the issue? @Steve Robbins

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing 502 Bad Gateway errors as well and it turns out that my disk quota had been reached.  I confirmed with my host and started removing old backups.  My site instantly came back.