# How change buffer-size in gunicorn(django) + nginx + docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi

My problem is that in some requests that application recive body size large(xml) and return xml large, the request returns 502. This occurs randomly.

I think that it's running buffer overflow.

My application running in docker with guinicorn like wsgi. And i want change value of buffer-size to 64k. how do I do that?

my gunicorn deploy command

```
python manage.py migrate && gunicorn backend.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3 --log-level=info
```

I can be mistaken, my base in:
[Nginx uwsgi (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697584/nginx-uwsgi-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-response-header-from-u)

Error log nginx

```
38286 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

Comment: your logs should tell you where the 502 comes from and what's the exact cause. What do you see in your gunicorn logs? nginx logs? of possibly even django logs?

Comment: I have the same question.  If you use uwsgi, you can specify a buffer size in your uswgi.ini file:

[uwsgi]
buffer-size     = 32768

But how can you do the same when using gunicorn?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? As I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an nginx issue, check out [client_max_body_size](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)

Comment: it will raise this error? I think that the nginx recive request and repass for gunicorn but for any reason dont finder the gunicorn(502 bad gateway).